# jQuery click function does not work properly on the 2nd run

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's a simplified version of my jQuery script that I cannot force to work properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/qk2nupq6/ (code's also below)

There's a "#press" div within a "#container". After pressing "#press", the content of "#container" is changed via .html() but the "#press" is still there so that is can be pressed again and the function can be run again.

For some reason, after pressing the button once, the function does not run again and I do not really have any clue why is that so.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="press">press </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#press").click(function(e){
        console.log("x");
        $("#container").html($("#container").html()+"<div>added</div>");
    })
})
```

Comment: You are destroying the existing elements (including any handler that is bound to them) and create new ones.

Comment: That is true, thank you. I was not sure what should I Google for (so that  could find the post you mentioned). Your suggestion and link to the other post about the issue solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you replace the innerHTML of the element the events bound to the elements are removed. So, when you replace the HTML even with the same content, previously bound events will not work.

Use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

Use `on` to bind event

```
$('#container').on('click', '#press', function() {
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container").on('click', "#press", function(e) {
    $("#container").html($("#container").html() + "<div>added</div>");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="press">press</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why should the OP do that? Please explain the issue.

Comment: @FelixKling Kindly check the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#press").on('click', function(e){
        console.log("x");
        $("#container").append("<div>added</div>");
    })
})
```

Here is the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qk2nupq6/3/).

**Explanation:**

> You were replacing the html of the element so, any event bound to it
>   were removed.

1. Use **Event Delegation:**

> Event delegation refers to the process of using event propagation
>   (bubbling) to handle events at a higher level in the DOM than the
>   element on which the event originated. It allows us to attach a single
>   event listener for elements that exist now or in the future. Inside
>   the Event Handling Function.

2. Or Append new data to existing element

Comment: This is a solution, but can you also explain what the issue is?

Comment: @FelixKling Please check the update.